# How to display List price,Price,You Save in Commerce Module using commerce discount module using view

Tags: views, commerce

I have used drupal commerce discount module. then I give the discount for particular product (admin/commerce/store/discounts).
and 
I have set the format of price (admin/commerce/products/types/product/display)
  Formated amount with saving(inline)
     Displaying a calculated price
     Showing: List price, Price, You save
     Labels shown
     Savings displayed as the percentage.

then I have check List price,price,You save in view price format but only price is display throught view.
but I want List Price,Price and You Save Display.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure commerce discount module integrates with views?

Comment: I have add view screenshot of commerce discount.